# actionScript getting data from next frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to export data for sprite animation. I have several MovieClips in a stage and keyframes with different positons/angle to make an animation.
When I try to write x,y data to a file I can't reach data outside of first frame.

```
function testWrite():void {
    var fileRef:FileReference;
    var txt:String;
    var fr:int;

    txt = "";

    // 'Head' is the name one of MovieClips
    for (fr = 0; fr < 4; fr++) {
        txt += "frame: " + currentFrame + ", " + Head.x + "\n";
        nextFrame();
        Head.nextFrame();
    }

    fileRef = new FileReference();
    fileRef.save(txt, "testExport.txt");
}
testWrite();
```

This is a function I'm using for it, but no matter if I use nextFrame() or gotoAndStop(x) it won't change frame.
Both Head.x and Head.currentFrame stays the same.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved it.

```
var txt:String = "";
stop();

function write():void {
    txt += Head.x + "\n";
}

function writeOut(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
    var file:FileReference;
    file = new FileReference();
    file.save(txt, "testExport.txt");
}

function frame(e:Event):void {
    if (currentFrame <= 3) {
        write();
        nextFrame();
    }
}

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frame); 
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, writeOut);
```